как сохранить данные через SharedPreferences, без нажатия на кнопку
Можно ли сохранять просто в onCreate или нужно обязательно привязывать к чему то?
В приложении пользователь будет вводить данные в EditText и они должны там появится и после перезахода. Как правильно сохранять их и где правильно присваивать самому EditText значение
strEditText1 = editText1.getText().toString();
editor.putString("editText1", strEditText1);
editText1.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("editText1", ""));

Вызываю это при onCreate и оно не сохраняет, так же пробовал сохранять при onPause

Официальная документация Передайте ключи и значения, которые вы хотите записать, с помощью таких методов, как putInt() и putString() . Затем вызовите apply() или commit(), чтобы сохранить изменения.

Сохранять в любом другом подходящем колбеке, например в onStop() активности. Для того чтобы сказать как правильно - покажите ваш неправильный код, мы же не знаем чего именно вы не знаете

В onCreate() считываем данные. В onPause() записываем.
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText editText1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText1 = findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    editText1.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("editText1", ""));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    String strEditText1 = editText1.getText().toString();
    editor.putString("editText1", strEditText1);
    editor.commit();
}

}

не работает так

@clay, работает

@woesss, если пытаюсь ввести текст в EditText, приложение вылетает. В чем может быть проблема?
editText.setText("text");

@clay Приведенный пример - рабочий, запускался в Android Studio.
Скопируйте себе его. Или покажите ваш код.

@clay, вы вообще читаете что вам пишут? Проблема в инициализации editText. Мы не видим ваш код как и где вы это делаете и есть ли он у вас вообще в макете нам неизвестно. Если у вас такой супер секретный код, что вы не можете его показать - сократите его до минимально воспроизводимого примера, как в данном ответе.
